# Displaying all the Odd number between 1 - 99 in java using Nested For Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

Currently I'm only able to display odd numbers of 1 3 5 7 9. However, I would like to display all the odd numbers from 1 - 99 with 9 rows and 5 col. May I know how am I able to display from 11 onwards rather than just 9 rows of 1 3 5 7 9.

Below is the code I'm stuck with.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=10; j++)
        {
            if (j%2 !=0)
            System.out.print(j + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: You should re-read how for loops work. In your current solution you are looping 10 times 9 times (sounds retarded, I know). My hint for you: you need only one loop.

Comment: I'm only able to display 1 3 5 7 9 for all the 9 rows but I wanted all the odd numbers from 1 - 99 for 9 rows.

Comment: Did they ask you to use nested loops? Because this can be achieved with one simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to calculate your number, try

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=10; j++)
        {
            int number = j+i*10
            if (number%2 !=0)
            System.out.print(number + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

but this problem you can solve with single loop

```
 for (int i=1; i<=99; i++)
 {
      if (number%2 !=0)
          System.out.print(number + " " );

      if (number%10 ==0)
          System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( i = 1; i < 100; i+=2 ) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            int c = j * 10 + i;
            if (c % 2 !=0)
                System.out.print(c + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Other alternative with just one loop:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 99; j += 2) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
        if ((j + 1) % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put `i += 2` instead of `i++` you can get rid of the modulus check. Functionally the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code now prints 9 rows of:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

This is happening because your inner loop loops on values between 1 and 9, always.

You should try something like:

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=99; i++) {
    if(i%2 != 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        counter++;
    }
    if(counter == 5) {
        System.out.println();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
1 3 5 7 9 
11 13 15 17 19 
21 23 25 27 29 
31 33 35 37 39 
41 43 45 47 49 
51 53 55 57 59 
61 63 65 67 69 
71 73 75 77 79 
81 83 85 87 89 
91 93 95 97 99
```

Comment: in your output, I don't understand why there are two spaces in 1st row? (I meant between numbers)

Comment: @Kent There shouldn't be, fixed :) Instinctively I aligned the table when I posted the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<=99; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 !=0)
        System.out.print(i + " " );
        if(i%10 == 0)
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This code will allow you to do what you want with 1 loop which is more efficient than using nested loops.

This will loop through each number from 1-99 and print if it is odd.  If the number is a multiple of 10 then it will print a new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a nested forloop you have to use both iterating variables to build your numbers. You dont use i at all in the inner for-loop. Therefore only 1 3 5 7 9 gets printed 9 times. For a hotfix try to use something like

```html
System.out.print(i + j + " " );
```

instead of

```html
System.out.print(j + " " );
```

note how i+j does not compute an addition here.
Anyway like pointed out in the comments you dont really need 2 loops here.

Answer (score 0):

### we cheat:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i += 2)
    System.out.printf("%d%s", i, i % 10 == 9 ? "\n" : " ");
```

### we check:

```
int c =0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)
    if ((i & 1) == 1) {
        c++;
        System.out.printf("%d%s", i, c % 5==0 ? "\n" : " ");
    }
```

**both output same, 5 odd numbers in a row, without trailing spaces.**

Answer (score 0):

With this one you can easily set the number of columns as you like it.

We use a single loop.

**Code:**

```
int columns = 5;
int start   = 1;
int end     = 99;

// iterate through every seconds i.
for (int i = start; i <= end; i += 2) {
    System.out.printf("%-4d", i);

    // if we have displayed enough words, start a new line
    if (i % (2 * columns) == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1   3   5   7   9   
11  13  15  17  19  
21  23  25  27  29  
31  33  35  37  39  
41  43  45  47  49  
51  53  55  57  59  
61  63  65  67  69  
71  73  75  77  79  
81  83  85  87  89  
91  93  95  97  99
```

However, if I understood your question correctly, you wanted to show numbers with 5 columns and 9 rows? Well this is impossible if we print only the numbers from 1 to 99. With 5 columns and numbers 1 to 99, you will get 10 rows.